# How to share only text to Instagram in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, instagram-api

How to share only text along with urls to Instagram from iOS applications.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to install this cocoapod by:

1. `cd` into the folder with the project
2. run `pod setup` to automatically create a podfile
3. add `pod 'ShareManager'` to your Podfile
4. and follow the instructions as described on the [ShareManagers GitHub site](https://github.com/imjerrybao/ShareManager)

Then you should be able to also share to Facebook, Twitter and more.

Comment: Thanks you and will check it and let you know. im thinking is it possible to share only text to instagram or no.

Answer (score 0):

You can't share text instagram from iOS application with url directly

Instagram dev team removed pre-filled caption(text) from sharing

check this link please [instagram dev](http://developers.instagram.com/post/125972775561/removing-pre-filled-captions-from-mobile-sharing)

but you can choice another way to share text

use `UIPasteboard` this is clipboard used in iOS System [UIPastelboard docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipasteboard)

copy text in iOS Application and paste it in Instagram.

some Instagram reposting iOS application use this solution to share text